# Image onError not triggered in Jasmine test using Karma and Phantom

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create a unit test for execution of the `onError` function for `Image` objects. However, the onError never seems to trigger. I imagine I am missing something important, not sure what the problem is.

Using a combination of `Jasmine`, `PhantomJS` and `Karma`.

See the most basic example for reference below.

```
it('should execute goddamn onerrors', function (done) {
    var image = new Image();

    // I have also tried onError with uppercase E.
    image.onerror = function () {
        done();
    };

    spyOn(image, 'onerror');

    image.src = 'www.domain.ex/test.jpg';

    expect(image.onerror).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Note that I have created several testcases, so excuse the language.

How can I test if the `onError` function gets triggered?